No OPENSSL_Applink when running pyinstaller compiled binary
I'm using pyinstaller to compile my python project. I do:
pyi-makespec main.py
pyinstaller main.spec

I've only added a file in the data variable of the main.spec
The build runs without any errors, but when I try to run dist\main.exe, I get: OPENSSL_Uplink(00007FF9C1CF8C88,08): no OPENSSL_Applink and the program does not even start.
Fun thing is, at first the program was running until a requests.get statement, that was giving the same error. I then tried to make a fresh install of conda with a fresh environment and all up to dates libraries, and now the program does not even launch.
I've tried to pass the libssl and libcrypto dlls to pyinstaller via the spec binaries variable, with no effect.
I don't understand where this error is coming from. Any help would be appreciated.
UPDATE: I found the line of code triggering the error. It's the last line of this snippet:
from _ssl import _SSLContext
context = _SSLContext(16)
context.keylog_filename = 'path'

The setter of the keylog_filename is defined in the cpython _ssl module like this:
_PySSLContext_set_keylog_filename(PySSLContext *self, PyObject *arg, void *c) {
  FILE *fp;
  /* Reset variables and callback first */
  SSL_CTX_set_keylog_callback(self->ctx, NULL);
  Py_CLEAR(self->keylog_filename);
  if (self->keylog_bio != NULL) {
      BIO *bio = self->keylog_bio;
      self->keylog_bio = NULL;
      PySSL_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
      BIO_free_all(bio);
      PySSL_END_ALLOW_THREADS
  }

  if (arg == Py_None) {
      /* None disables the callback */
      return 0;
  }

  /* _Py_fopen_obj() also checks that arg is of proper type. */
  fp = _Py_fopen_obj(arg, "a" PY_STDIOTEXTMODE);
  if (fp == NULL)
      return -1;

  self->keylog_bio = BIO_new_fp(fp, BIO_CLOSE | BIO_FP_TEXT);
  if (self->keylog_bio == NULL) {
      PyErr_SetString(get_state_ctx(self)->PySSLErrorObject,
                      "Can't malloc memory for keylog file");
      return -1;
  }
  self->keylog_filename = Py_NewRef(arg);

  /* Write a header for seekable, empty files (this excludes pipes). */
  PySSL_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
  if (BIO_tell(self->keylog_bio) == 0) {
      BIO_puts(self->keylog_bio,
             "# TLS secrets log file, generated by OpenSSL / Python\n");
    (void)BIO_flush(self->keylog_bio);
  }
  PySSL_END_ALLOW_THREADS
  SSL_CTX_set_keylog_callback(self->ctx, _PySSL_keylog_callback);
  return 0;
}

I'm still unsure what line of this code is problematic tho.
